# Check multiple table size in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

i found this query on how to check the size of a table in Postgres

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('the_table'));
```

I want to get the size from multiple tables.
My database has this kind of table name:

```
tblresource_01012014
tblresource_02012014
tblresource_03012014
...
```

It has date on its name. i want to get the size for a specific month. something like,

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('tblresource_**012014'));
```

Absolutely this query is wrong. anybody knows what are the right query to execute

**MY SOLUTION**
Hey guys, for now i have a solution for this which is quite simple but i wont say it as a good answer though cause it might only works for my case. and doesn't fully meet my goal. here how i do it.

```
select table_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(table_name))
from information_schema.tables
where table_name like 'tblresource_%012014'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the values using a query:

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('tblresource_' || lpad(n.n::varchar, 2, '0') || '012014'))
from generate_series(1, 12) n(n)
```

Comment: nitpicking : what if `tblresource_12012014` doesn't exists ??

Comment: @unique_id . . . Then the query will generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl tbl_name
    ,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(format('%s', t.tbl))) size
FROM (
    SELECT table_name tbl
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
        AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
        AND table_name ilike '%tblresource_%' --your table
        AND table_name ilike '%012014' --to search 
    ) t;
```

[**sqlfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d946a/1)

---

You can wrap above select into a function like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tblresource_size (_yr TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (
        tbl_name TEXT
        ,size TEXT
        ) AS $$

BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY

    SELECT tbl::TEXT tbl_name
        ,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(format('%s', t.tbl))) size
    FROM (
        SELECT table_name tbl
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'public'
            AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND table_name ilike '%tblresource_%'
            AND table_name ilike '%' || _yr || '' --012014 will come here
        ) t;
END $$

LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

function call :

```
select * from get_tblresource_size('012014') --passing the search value
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will returns sum of two tables with union,split_part and sum functions.

```
select sum(sizeByte) from (select split_part(pg_size_pretty(hypertable_size('table1')), ' ', 1)::bigint *
case split_part(pg_size_pretty(hypertable_size('table1')), ' ', 2)
  when 'bytes' then 1
  when 'kB' then 1024
  when 'MB' then 1024*1024
  when 'GB' then 1024*1024*1024
  when 'TB' then 1024*1024*1024*1024::bigint
end as sizeByte
union
select split_part(pg_size_pretty(hypertable_size('table2')), ' ', 1)::bigint *
case split_part(pg_size_pretty(hypertable_size('table2')), ' ', 2)
  when 'bytes' then 1
  when 'kB' then 1024
  when 'MB' then 1024*1024
  when 'GB' then 1024*1024*1024
  when 'TB' then 1024*1024*1024*1024::bigint
end as sizeByte) t;
```